# My key press capturing script is not working in Firefox, why?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, input

I found a script that can handle input for a small HTML5 based game I'm building:

```
var KEY = {W: 87, A: 65, S:83, D: 68, E: 69};

var input = {
    right: false,
    up: false,
    left: false,
    down: false,
    e: false
};

function press() 
{
    if (!ni)
    {
        var evt=window.event;
        var code = evt.keyCode;

        switch(code) 
        {
            case KEY.W: input.up = true; break;
            case KEY.A: input.left = true; break;
            case KEY.S: input.down = true; break;
            case KEY.D: input.right = true; break;
            case KEY.E: input.e = true; break;
        }
    }
}

function release()
{
    if (!ni)
    {
        evt=window.event;
        var code = evt.keyCode; 
        input.code = code;

        switch(code) 
        {
            case KEY.W: input.up = false; break;
            case KEY.A: input.left = false; break;
            case KEY.S: input.down = false; break;
            case KEY.D: input.right = false; break;        
            case KEY.E: input.e = false; break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the event handlers are assigned:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", press);
document.addEventListener("keyup", release);
```

The variable `ni` that shows up occasionally is true when the player is entering text in a text box, I'm pretty sure that it isn't causing the problems. Also, this works perfectly in chrome, but as I said, doesn't work in Firefox. Anybody care to explain why? Firefox version: 10.0.2.4428.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **non-standard** `window.event` object is only available in IE and Chrome.

In standard-compliant browsers, the `event` object is passed as a first argument to the event listener.

Change:

```
function press() {
    if (!ni) {
        var evt=window.event;
```

to:

```
function press(evt) {              // <-- Declaration of evt
    if (!ni) {
        evt = evt || window.event; // <-- Notice: var is omitted
```

Equivalently:

```
function release(evt) {
```

Answer (score -1):

In firefox you need to use `e.which` instead of `e.keyCode`.

You can make it compatible with:

var keyCode = e.which || w.keyCode;